# PHP header wont redirect with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, rest, header

For a project we have to create a basic log in system.  Im trying to use REST to manage my entire page.  Now I believe Im missing or misunderstanding some key concept here but I've been trying to figure out how to do this for ages.  Were not allowed to use libraries for this exercise so I cant use JQuery.

So heres my problem:  I have a .js file that checks for username length and password length and etc.... in this .js file I also have an ajax function that sends the username and email to PHP to verify that there is not already an existing user with that email or username using SQL.

```
function checkUser()
        {
            var ajax = new Ajax(); // instantiates my external ajax class
            var email = document.getElementById("newEmail").value;
            var username = document.getElementById("newUserName").value
            ajax.post("index.php?method=register&check=check", "newEmail=" + email + "&newUserName=" + username, callbackCatch)

        }
    function callbackCatch(param)   
        {
            var responseMessages = JSON.parse(param.responseText);

            emailMessage = responseMessages.emailMessage;
            userNameMessage = responseMessages.userNameMessage;
            userEmailIsOk = responseMessages.userEmailIsOk;
            userNameIsOk = responseMessages.userNameIsOk;
            release = true;
            if((userEmailIsOk + userNameIsOk) != 2)
                {
                    console.log(userEmailIsOk + userNameIsOk);
                    release = false;
                }

            updateMessageFields();
        }
```

I get a JSON string back which I parse and then compare against my form values.  When everything is find and dandy i click the register button on my form page which posts all the fields back to my php file.  However it seems that when i do this my external ajax class is accessed somehow every time and I get an error : NS_NOINTERFACE: Component does not have requested interface.

Im assuming that because AJAX is running in the backgroud whenever I make a post, even from my form it tries to send back my param which in this case are not compatible.

I dont know how to fix this.  My PHP file that is suppose to handle the transfer looks like this:

```
require_once("../database/table.php");
```

class test  {

```
private $SQLtable;

private $newEmail;
private $newPswrd;
private $newUserName;
private $newFullName;


public function test()
    {
        $this->SQLtable = new table();
        $this->initClassVars();
        $this->generateUserName();
        $this->regUser();


    }
function initClassVars()
    {
        if(isset($_POST["newPassword"]))
            {
                $this->newPswrd = $_POST["newPassword"];
            }
        if(isset($_POST['newUserName']))
            {
                $this->newUserName = $_POST['newUserName'];
            }
        if(isset($_POST["newEmail"]))
            {
                $this->newEmail = $_POST["newEmail"];
            }
        if(isset($_POST["newFullName"]))
            {
                $this->newFullName = $_POST["newFullName"];
            }
    }
function generateUserName()
    {
        if(isset($_POST["newFullName"]))
        {
            $suggestedUserName = str_replace(" ", "", $this->newFullName);
            $this->newUserName = $suggestedUserName;
        }
    }

function regUser()
    {       

                $this->SQLtable->registerUser($this->newEmail, $this->newPswrd, $this->newFullName, $this->newUserName);
                $sessionKey = $this->genKey();
                $this->SQLtable->authUser($this->newEmail, $this->newPswrd, $sessionKey);
                header("location:Location:index.php?method=feed&key=$sessionKey&user=$this->newEmail");
                exit;
    }

function genKey($length = 16)
    {
        $options = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"; //Range
        $key = ""; //Empty holder for key
        for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
            {
                $code = rand(0, strlen($options) - 1); 
                $key .= $options[$code];  // Loops through as long as the $length is set and adds a random string char from $options to build a new key.
            }
        return $key;
    }
```

}

As you can see Im toying around with using an API key to control authentication.  I havent gotten the cookies working with it yet, but ill do that after I figure out how to get this registration thing sorted.

Sorry if ive been unclear.  This is my first question on stackoverflow and basically I never wrote a line of code in my life until about 8 months ago so bear with my newbish code :D.  Thanks..

Ok so heres the HTML and where the functions are being called:
This is my form html file.  The doctype and header are added separately as I use them over and over a few times.

```
<body>

<h1> Thanks! <!-- $user -->, you're almost there.  We just need a few more details      </h1>

<form id="registerUser" name="registerUser" action="index.php?method=test" method="post">
<p>
<label for="newFullName">Full Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="newFullName" name="newFullName" value="$newFullName" />
<span id="nameMessage"></span>
</p>
<p>
<label for="newUserName">User Name: </label>
<input type = "text" id="newUserName" name="NewUserName" value="$newUserName" />
<span id="nicknameMessage"><!-- $newUserNameMessage --></span>
</p>
<p>
<label for="newEmail">Email: </label>
<input type="text" id="newEmail" name="newEmail" value="$newEmail" />
<span id = "newEmailMessage"><!-- $newEmailMessage --></span>
</p>
<p>
<label for ="newPassword">Password: </label>
<input type="password" id="newPassword" name="newPassword" value="$newPswrd" />
<span id = "newPasswordMessage"></span>
</p>
<input type="submit" id="register" disabled="disabled" value="Register" onclick=""/>
</form>


<p><a href="../../../Index.html"> Click here to go back to the login site and login.   </a></p>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../js/net/ajaxHandler.js">    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">var bootstrap = new ajaxHandler();     bootstrap.init(); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The entire JS file is this.. its a bit messy but its because Ive been toying with it so much:

```
var ajaxHandler = function()
{
    var self = this;
    var release = true;
    var nameField;
    var userField;
    var emailField;
    var passWordField
    var emailMessage;
    var userNameMessage;

    self.init = function()
        {
            addEventListeners();
            checkFormForErrors();
        }

    self.redirect = function ()
        {
        }
    function addEventListeners()
        {
            nameField       = document.getElementById("newFullName");
            userField       = document.getElementById("newUserName");
            emailField      = document.getElementById("newEmail");
            passWordField   = document.getElementById("newPassword");

            Event.addEventListener(nameField, 'click', checkFormForErrors);
            Event.addEventListener(userField, 'click', checkUser);
            Event.addEventListener(emailField, 'click', checkUser);
            Event.addEventListener(passWordField, 'click', checkFormForErrors);

            Event.addEventListener(nameField, 'keyup', checkFormForErrors);
            Event.addEventListener(userField, 'keyup', checkUser);
            Event.addEventListener(emailField, 'keyup', checkUser);
            Event.addEventListener(passWordField, 'keyup', checkFormForErrors);
        }

    function checkPassword()
        {
        var passWordIsOk;
        var patt        = /\s/;
        var whiteSpace  = patt.test(passWordField);
        var passwordLength = passWordField.value.length;
        if (passwordLength < 8 )
            {
                document.getElementById("newPasswordMessage").innerHTML = "Your passowrd must be at least 8 charachters long. ";
                passWordIsOk = false
                if (whiteSpace)
                    {
                        document.getElementById("newPasswordMessage").innerHTML += "Your Password cannot contain any spaces.";
                        passWordIsOk = false
                    }
            } 
        else
            {
                document.getElementById("newPasswordMessage").innerHTML = "Password looks good";
                passWordIsOk = true
            }
        return passWordIsOk;
        }

    function checkName()    
        {
            var userNameIsOk;
            var nameMessage = document.getElementById("nameMessage");
            if (!nameField.value)
                {
                    nameMessage.innerHTML = "You need to enter a name."
                    userNameIsOk = false;

                }
            else
                {
                    nameMessage.innerHTML = "Name looks great."
                    userNameIsOk = true;
                }
            return userNameIsOk;
        }

    function checkEmailSyntax()
        {
            var EmailIsOk = true
            var patt    = /^([\w!.%+\-])+@([\w\-])+(?:\.[\w\-]+)+$/ ;
            var format  = patt.test(emailField.value);
            if (!format)
                {
                    document.getElementById("newEmailMessage").innerHTML = "Your email does not appear to be in the right format."
                    EmailIsOk = false;
                }
            return EmailIsOk        
        }

    function checkFullNameSyntax()
        {
            var nameIsOk = true
            if (document.getElementById("newUserName").value == "")
                {
                    document.getElementById("nicknameMessage").innerHTML = "You must enter a username.  You can always change it later."
                    nameIsOk = false
                }
            return nameIsOk;
        }

    function checkUser()
        {
            var ajax = new Ajax();
            var email = document.getElementById("newEmail").value;
            var username = document.getElementById("newUserName").value
            ajax.post("index.php?method=register&check=check", "newEmail=" + email + "&newUserName=" + username, callbackCatch)

        }
    function callbackCatch(param)   
        {
            var responseMessages = JSON.parse(param.responseText);

            emailMessage = responseMessages.emailMessage;
            userNameMessage = responseMessages.userNameMessage;
            userEmailIsOk = responseMessages.userEmailIsOk;
            userNameIsOk = responseMessages.userNameIsOk;
            release = true;
            if((userEmailIsOk + userNameIsOk) != 2)
                {
                    console.log(userEmailIsOk + userNameIsOk);
                    release = false;
                }

            updateMessageFields();
            var ajax = "";
        }
    function updateMessageFields()
        {
            document.getElementById("nicknameMessage").innerHTML = userNameMessage;
            document.getElementById("newEmailMessage").innerHTML = emailMessage;
            checkFormForErrors();

        }
    function checkFormForErrors()
        {
            console.log('hi');
            var nameOk = checkFullNameSyntax()
            console.log(nameOk);
            var passOk = checkPassword()
            console.log(passOk);
            var userOk = checkName()
            console.log(userOk);    
            var emailOk = checkEmailSyntax()
            console.log(emailOk);
            console.log(release);
            document.getElementById("register").disabled = true;
            if(release && nameOk && passOk && userOk && emailOk)
                {
                    console.log('hey');
                    console.log(release && nameOk && passOk && userOk && emailOk)
                    document.getElementById("register").disabled = false;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: So your main problem is the redirect from PHP? Which happens when you call it with AJAX?

Comment: Yeah I believe so.  under regUser()  i want to to send the page to index.php again with a different method.  Then that method instantiates my users home page with another php class.

Comment: Change it around so that if successful, your AJAX request returns the URL to redirect to, then in the success callback use document.location.href = [url] to complete the redirect

Comment: I suppose I could to that.  I was just hoping not have to pass a bunch of variables back to my javascript.  The only reason I have javascript in the first place was to show the user isntantaneously if there username password...etc.. were ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this will be hard to understand, but by the time your AJAX receives the response, the page has already been redirected...and to your AJAX, it looks normal - it's getting a response back (in this case, a full page, not JSON). This is the order of events:

```
AJAX Request

--> Browser sends request to PHP file

----> Your PHP file receives the request, processes it, and "redirects"

<---- HTTP 302 status code sent to browser

<-- Browser receives 302 status code, redirects response, and returns result as AJAX response
```

At least I'm pretty sure that's what happens - I swear I've ran into this "problem" before, and I found out this is what was happening.

To "fix" this, you have a few options. Instead of using PHP to "redirect", you could send this information in your JSON. Then, in your callback, you could check for its existence...like a "redirect" key, and use its value to redirect to (setting its value in PHP as the URL to redirect to). Or, you could keep it as a string, and before you parse it, check for it starting with "redirect:". If it starts with that, get the rest of the string and redirect to that value (settings its value in PHP as the URL to redirect to). Otherwise, parse it like JSON and process it normally.

Comment: Ok so, because I have an instance of ajax running, it processes my form submit and returns the status and redirects instead of allowing php to set it?  I think I understand anyways.  The shame is that I also have a log in page aside from this registration page where my form and POST action works perfectly

Comment: @ChrisShields Hmm not really. AJAX isn't "running". When you make an AJAX request, it's asynchronous to the rest of your code. It makes a special HTTP request in the background of the webpage. You set it up so it knows what code to run when its response is received (the callback). Normal POST submissions work fine because it's a normal operation of redirecting. Because it's an AJAX request in this case, the browser handles the response a little differently, and messes up what you expect. You just have to code for it a little differently, as we've pointed out - probably setting it in the JSON

Comment: Yeah i figured it had something to do with that.  I still dont see how my form is tied to my ajax code written in my javascript file though.  if I had some sort of function that was listening to my form then I would understand.  But the only ajax code I have in my js are those 2 functions ive shown here.  And those functions are ONLY called when i click on the fields, I have no event listeners tied to the form itself or the submit button.  Thats whats confusing me so much

Comment: Can you show where these functions are being called exactly? And/or the relevant HTML? Maybe we can explain what's happening that way

Comment: Ok ive updated my question to include the HTML and the full js class

Comment: @ChrisShields Ahh okay, the `addEventListeners` function adds the "click" and "keyup" events to the specific elements, so that they run `checkFormForErrors` or `checkUser`. Does that make sense? Since you run `var bootstrap = new ajaxHandler(); bootstrap.init();`, it calls the `init` function and therefore calls `addEventListeners` and does several other things.

Comment: Unbelievable...sometimes when something goes wrong I apparently have the need to look WAY to deeply into why and I miss the obvious simple problem.... :p.  If I remove the click event listeners it works.  The only part im not clear on is just how the elements listen for click.  I have all my click listeners on the input fields themselves except for the input "submit" element.  But apparently the evnetlistener fires when I click on the submit element anyways?  Why would my event listeners fire when clicking on a non listening input element?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redirect from php in an ajax call.

You need to send the right information back from your php script to your javascript and do the redirect from there, using the parameters you got back from php.

You also have one `Location:` too many in your php, but that is not the problem here.

Comment: When I click on the input="submit" button is that an AJAX call?  because in my log in page when I click submit the POST is sent properly to PHP and the redirect happens with out a problem.

Comment: @Chris Shields You should know that :-) Without seeing your html and javascript I don't know if you are catching the from submit event, button click event or whatever in javascript.

Comment: Yeah, its just that i figured a form does its own seperate AJAX call apart from the ajax that I have instantiated.  My form looks like this:

Comment: ah.... too big to copy in here.  Its just a regular form 

    <form id="registerUser" name="registerUser" action="index.php?method=test" method="post">
    <input type="submit" id="register" disabled="disabled" value="Register" onclick=""/>

Comment: well.. ive never used jsfiddle.net.  It looks as though it uses libraries which unfortunately we aren't suppose to use for this exercise

Comment: @ChrisShields jsfiddle.net is used as an area for you to test HTML/Javascript/CSS. It allows you to easily copy/paste your code into there and run it as if you had a webpage setup and had inserted your code there. It's convenient that way, and it allows for you to "save" one and share it with others to view/edit. It also allows you to use/add libraries (some come standard, but aren't required), and allows you to modify a lot of things